# Find big O notation with Rabin-Miller implementation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I’ve got a question about trying to decide the big O notation for a Rabin-Miller algorithm I have implemented.

When generating a

```
 512 bits prime, I get a runtime of   22 seconds,
1024 takes                           237 seconds,
2048 takes                          2942 seconds.
```

How can I determine the big O notation for these values? It seems to me that the runtime increases by *roughly* 10 times everytime the bitsize increases by 2. Does that mean that it’s `O(10n)`?

Comment: I think you ment `O(10^n)`

Comment: @Filip Haglund: *exponential* complexity - `O(10^n)` - is typical for *naive* tests (say, checking in a loop), **Rabin Miller** test is a *polynomial* algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You have *too few* points to estimate the function (and `O(function)` as well) from the experiment.

```
   x | f(x)
-----------
 512 |   22
1024 |  237
2048 | 2942
```

If we test `O(n)` (`O(10n)` is in fact `O(n)`) as `f(x) = Ax + B` guess with a help of [Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) method, we'll get a good fit

```
A =     2.0
B = -1330.5
R =     0.964   (Correlation)
```

However, many *alternative* functions have *better* support

```
f(x) = Ax**4 + B  with correlation R = 0.99990 <- actual best fit
f(x) = Ax**3 + B         -/-       R = 0.99937 <- expected
f(x) = Ax**2 + B         -/-       R = 0.99232
```

you want *more points* to find out the right function: when having *three* values only `Ax**4 + B` (which corresponds to `O(x**4)`) is the *leader* so far, but we can't reject the [expected complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) which is `Ax**3 + B`.

Finally, we can *guess* (we can't *conclude* with three points only) that the implementation is *suboptimal*: `O(x**4)` instead of expected `O(x**3)`

If our guess `O(x**4)` is correct one, than we might expect that doubling `x`: `x -> 2 * x` we increase the time `16-fold` (`2**4 == 16`)